# Where is truffle IDE after installation?

Tags: solidity, truffle, ide

I have installed truffle using `npm install -g truffle` (windows), however I cannot find truffle IDE editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truffle isn't an IDE, it's a cli framework for developing smart contracts/dapps